# How can I print values below a certain X value from a GGPLOT in R?

Tags: r

I've made a bar plot in R that has height on the x axis and number of students on the y axis. I'm looking to print the number of students who are shorter than a specific height (say 5'6). How can I do this using R?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```r
library(ggplot2)

# example height data from Utts and Heckard
chap4heights <- read.csv(
    "http://www.math.yorku.ca/people/georges/Files/NATS1500/Data/chap4-heights.csv", 
    row.names = 1)

ggplot(data=chap4heights, aes(Height)) + 
    geom_bar() + 
    # print number of people with heights shorter than 66in over the bars
    stat_count(data = chap4heights[chap4heights$Height < 66,], 
        geom = 'text', 
        aes(label = ..count..), 
        vjust=0) + 
    # print cumulative count of all people shorter than 66in
    annotate('text', 
        x = 65, 
        y = 10, 
        label = sum(chap4heights$Height<66), 
        size = 12, 
        col = 'red')
```

I printed the number of people at specific heights less than 5'6" above their respective bars. 
I also printed the total number of people shorter than 5'6" in red at specified coordinates.

[image: Height example]

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! I actually only need to print this number (35) in the R studio console, not the graph! Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: @Sarah `sum(chap4heights$Height<66)` - this function takes the sum of all TRUE values where the `Height` values in the dataset is less than 66 inches.